# Translation animation of large image from top to bottom Android

Tags: android, animation, imageview, translation

I'm trying to develop a splash screen with a large image scrolling (Animating) from top to bottom.
I dont think using ScrollView would be good since I dont want the user to scroll the image.

This is what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: use handler with a sleep with scrollTo by some value till bottom or height of bitmap

Comment: it's not called translation animation but TranslateAnimation,  try it out

Comment: @Manmohan if you use a Handler no sleep is needed,  its useless  in that case

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="200" 
      android:fromYDelta="-100%p" 
      android:toYDelta="100%p"
      >
</translate> 

</set>
```

create this animation as slidedown.xml in an anim folder in the project and use the code below in the java file that has the view.You may change the values of "android:fromYdelta" according to your need.

```
myImageView.startAnimation(slidedown);
```

Comment: this is going to be very fast!

Comment: increase android:duration :)

Answer (score 0):

For example if your imageview is 250 px use :

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myImageView, "translationY", 250);
```

And in xml set on your imageview  :

```
android:translationY="-250"
```